# Div underneath Header still overflowing why?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header and have the div underneath it be height:100% with overflow and not using the overflow-y:hidden;command. I accomplished this before, but not working anymore. You should be able to scroll vertically within the Left Div, but no overflow within the body.

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/edcp1poc/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>  

<div class="left">Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
background-color: #666666;
min-width:100%;
height:60px;
margin-top: -60px;
}

.left {
height: 100%;
width:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -60px;
}

body, html {
height: 100%   
}

body {
padding:60px 0 0 0px; /* 60 — header height*/
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: that what you looking for?http://jsfiddle.net/edcp1poc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box-sizing:border-box;` is making your `div` have it's absolute size unchanged (including margin, border and padding values) effectively shrinking the box to include margin,padding,borders inside the `div` area.

Your `.left` box height is 100% - that means it's 100% of its parents element, which here is site `body` and `body` height is 100% and its parent height is widow size.

Default behavior is to add margin, border and padding values to elements height and width thus its height is 100% + margin-top + margin-bottom + padding-top + padding-bottom + border-top + border-bottom

So if you add 2 elements with height 60px and 100% the full site height is 100% widow height + 60px, thats why the scroll appears.

You can also calculate `.left` height using `calc()` function

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%   
}

body {
    margin:0;
}

.main {
    background-color: #666666;
    min-width:100%;
    height:60px;
}

.left {
    height: calc(100% - 62px); 
  /*62px is .main height + .left 1px border-top + 1px border-bottom */
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid black; /* additional 2px to width and height of this block */
    float:left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* or with box-sizing changed */
.left {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    /* box model changed, just pass elements height */
    height: calc(100% - 60px); 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>  

<div class="left">Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div Left Div 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edcp1poc/5/

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have to apply a **overflow: scroll;** to the .left class and a **overflow: hidden;** to the body.

CSS:

```
.main {
background-color: #666666;
min-width:100%;
height:60px;
margin-top: -60px;
}

.left {
height: 100%;
width:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: -60px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

body {
padding:60px 0 0 0px; /* 60 — header height*/
margin:0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/undcg4oe/

Comment: I am trying to do this without applying overflow:hidden; to the body. I did it before and just trying to retrace but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, but I do not understand why can someone explain it to me please?

When adding this it seems to work:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box; 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edcp1poc/4/

I have updated it and when adding that to the CSS it works just fine the left is height 100% and adjusts with the window size. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I think there was an issue with a margin or padding. Border-box makes border, padding and margin fit into your width. http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: I removed margin-top: -60px from the left div. But when you remove the border-box css elements, an overflow-y is created. I don't understand why because like you said, "border-box makes borders." If you remove the border-box css elements you can try it out in JSFiddle just by simply removing the *{box-sizing}

Comment: I've explained it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136050/div-underneath-header-still-overflowing-why/28137151#28137151